# How to download a YouTube video using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, video, download, youtube-api, media

I'm trying to make a Youtube video downloader software using VB.net and some API called [LibVideo](https://github.com/i3arnon/libvideo) , [LibVideoNuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLibrary/) well it did work for few days but since Youtube announced that it will start using some Video encryption methods to ensure security whenever i paste a Youtube video link and hit Download button it gives me: “GetDecryptionFunction Failed” , this Library works in 10% of youtube video , it works in this video [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=668nUCeBHyY) , i found an official youtube API for .NET programs but it doesn't seem to give you the access to play or download the Youtube Video it only give some features such as upload videos, manage playlists and subscriptions, update channel settings..., well here is my code if it helps :

```
        Dim Video = YouTube.Default.GetVideo(youtubeURL.Text)
        Me.SaveFileDialog1.FileName = Video.FullName
        If Me.SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Me.whereToSave = Me.SaveFileDialog1.FileName

            Me.SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ""

            Me.Label6.Text = "Save to: " & Me.whereToSave

            Me.youtubeURL.Enabled = False
            Me.getThumbailButton.Enabled = False
            Me.btnCancel.Enabled = True

            Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() 'Start download
            progressupdatertimer.Start()
            largeImage.Image = My.Resources.loading
            resoltuion.Text = "Resolution: " & Video.Resolution
            bitrate.Text = "Bitrate: " & Video.AudioBitrate
            Dim filesizekb As Long = Math.Round((filesize / 1024), 2)
            Dim filesizemb As Long = Math.Round((filesizekb / 1024), 2)
            filesizemb2 = filesizemb
            Label11.Text = filesizemb2 & " MB"
        End If
```

GetDecryptionFunction Failed

Comment: YouTube in general doesn't want you to be able to do this. Developers of the various download tools and websites have been doing this dance with YouTube for years now. Even if you can figure out how to decrypt the current videos, i guarantee YouTube will make some future change that will again cause your code to be unable to download them. Rinse, Repeat.

Comment: but in their terms of service they said i  can download videos for personal use like listening to music , or watching a video my programs are not for commercial use . thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of LibVideo made a workout and it's working now , You can use it for your personal use.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading videos from YouTube is not something that Google wants you doing.  Videos are uploaded to them by the owner of the video and you downloading them would be taking something that you do not own.  That being said people do the same with images for years and that is possible.

From the [YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) Section 5.1L:

> you agree not to access Content or any reason other than your personal, non-commercial use solely as intended through and permitted by the normal functionality of the Service, and solely for Streaming. "Streaming" means a contemporaneous digital transmission of the material by YouTube via the Internet to a user operated Internet enabled device in such a manner that the data is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user;

The YouTube api is mostly a file system api.  It will allow you to upload videos to your own account but it does not have the ability to download videos even ones that you yourself own.

If you do manage to find a library that works to download videos its not going to be anything officially supported by Google and your probably going against one of their terms of services by even attempting to download the videos.

Comment: the program i make is for personal use only , all the program i make works the same way i just make them to make my life easier and for fun of course , thank you for clearing things out.